# Creating a rectangle within a class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

So basically I'm trying to figure out how to implement rectangles with in a class around each bullet I fire. It's a missile command type game. What I can't figure out is WHERE I would declare the Rectangle and how I would pass it to the game.

Here the code for my rocket class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace ShootingRocket
{
public class Rocket
{
    public Texture2D DrawTexture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Direction { get; set; }
    public float Rotation { get; set; }
    public float Speed { get; set; }
    public bool IsShooting { get; set; }

    int timeBetweenShots = 100;
    int shotTimer = 0;

    public Rocket(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Vector2 direction, float rotation, float Speed)
    {
        this.DrawTexture = texture;
        this.Position = position;
        this.Direction = direction;
        this.Rotation = rotation;
        this.Speed = Speed;

        this.IsShooting = false;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        this.Position += Direction * Speed;

        if (IsShooting)
        {
            shotTimer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

            if (shotTimer > timeBetweenShots)
            {
                shotTimer = 0;

                ProjectileManager.AddBullet(this.Position, this.Direction, 12, 2000, BulletType.Player);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            this.DrawTexture,
            this.Position,
            null,
            Color.White,
            this.Rotation,
            new Vector2(
                this.DrawTexture.Width / 2,
                this.DrawTexture.Height / 2),
            1.0f,
            SpriteEffects.None,
            1.0f);
```

Here is the code for my bullet class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace ShootingRocket
{
public enum BulletType { Player, Enemy }

public class Bullet
{
    public BulletType Type { get; set; }
    public Texture2D DrawTexture { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Direction { get; set; }
    public float Speed { get; set; }
    public int ActiveTime { get; set; }
    public int TotalActiveTime { get; set; }

    public Bullet(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Vector2 direction, float speed, int activeTime, BulletType type)
    {
        this.DrawTexture = texture;
        this.Position = position;
        this.Direction = direction;
        this.Speed = speed;
        this.ActiveTime = activeTime;
        this.Type = type;

        this.TotalActiveTime = 0;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        this.Position += Direction * Speed;

        this.TotalActiveTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(
             DrawTexture,
             Position,
             null,
             Color.White,
             0f,
             new Vector2(
                  DrawTexture.Width / 2,
                  DrawTexture.Height / 2),
             1.0f,
             SpriteEffects.None,
             0.8f);
    }
}
}
```

And last but not least my Projectile Manager class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace ShootingRocket
{
public class ProjectileManager : DrawableGameComponent
{
    static List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>();
    static Texture2D playerBulletTexture;

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public ProjectileManager(Game game, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        : base(game)
    {
        game.Components.Add(this);
        playerBulletTexture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bullet");

        this.spriteBatch = spriteBatch;
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        {
            bullets[i].Update(gameTime);

            if (bullets[i].TotalActiveTime > bullets[i].ActiveTime)
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (Bullet b in bullets)
        {
            b.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    public static void AddBullet(Vector2 position, Vector2 direction, float speed, int activeTime, BulletType type)
    {
        bullets.Add(new Bullet(playerBulletTexture, position, direction, speed,       activeTime, type));
    }
}
}
```

any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
public Rectangle collisionRec {get; private set;}
```

Then in the update method of the bullet you update the rectangle coordinates.

```
collisionRec = new Rectangle(position.X, position.Y, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
```

You are probably maintaining a list of all those bullets in game1 or somewhere.

```
foreach (Bullet b in bulletList)
{
if (b.collisionRec.Intersects(someOtherRec))
    {
     //Do some stuff.
    }
}
```